# Why can Firefox not allow permanent access to my screen?

Tags: macos, firefox, screen-sharing

When I join a Google Hangout and try to share my entire screen, Firefox always prompts me whether to share a window or the entire screen. I always want to share the entire screen. But when I enable the checkbox for "Remember this decision" I get this warning: `Firefox can not allow permanent access to your screen.`

Why does this happen? Is it because I'm on a Mac, or is it specific to macOS Catalina?

[image]

Comment: I would think it is a *security* issue.

Comment: @SteveChambers I'm pretty sure there was a time when I didn't get this prompt, so I guess my question is what changed?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a Mac specific problem. I saw the same message on Windows and solved it with following steps:

1. Write `about:config` to url searchbox and press Enter. You will see advanced Firefox settings.
2. Create variable `full-screen-api.approval-required` and set it to `true`.
3. That's it, you are now allowed to share your screen with Firefox.

Comment: This had potential, but I still get the same prompt after setting the variable as described here. :(

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked on Fedora 33 Linux! :)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me share my entire screen on Linux KDE Neon. Firefox still doesn't allow permanent access but temporary is ok with me, as long as I can share the entire screen at once.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please uncheck    "Remember this decision" ?
That should solve the problem ....

Comment: This prevents the error message but doesn't fix the actual issue.

Comment: The question is about allowing permanent access. If you uncheck the option, the expected result will never be achieved by definition. Terrible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could post this question on the Mozilla support forum for Firefox,  using this link :

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/new/desktop